# Multiple files in to folder

Tags: javascript, php, html, cakephp

Hello I have a view file and controller, what makes multiple inputs where I can upload files in to folder, but its uploading only one file in to folder. I know what is problem, but I dont know how to fix this or how to do this.

**My Controller:**

```
public function uploadFile() {
        $filename = '';
            if ($this->request->is('post')) { // checks for the post values
                $uploadData = $this->data['files'];
                //print_r($this->data['files']); die;
                if ( $uploadData['size'] == 0 || $uploadData['error'] !== 0) { // checks for the errors and size of the uploaded file
                    echo "Failide maht kokku ei tohi olla üle 5MB";
                    return false;
                }
                $filename = basename($uploadData['name']); // gets the base name of the uploaded file
                $uploadFolder = WWW_ROOT. 'files';  // path where the uploaded file has to be saved
                $filename = $filename; // adding time stamp for the uploaded image for uniqueness
                $uploadPath =  $uploadFolder . DS . $filename;
                if( !file_exists($uploadFolder) ){
                    mkdir($uploadFolder); // creates folder if  not found
                }
                if (!move_uploaded_file($uploadData['tmp_name'], $uploadPath)) {
                    return false;
                } 
                echo "Sa sisestasid faili(d): $filename";

            }           
    }
```

**My View file:**

```
<?php
    echo $this->Form->create('uploadFile', array( 'type' => 'file'));
?>

    <div class="input_fields_wrap">

        <label for="uploadFilefiles"></label>
        <input type="file" name="data[files]" id="uploadFilefiles">

    </div>

<button type="button" class="add_field_button">+</button> <br><br>

    <form name="frm1" method="post" onsubmit="return greeting()">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

<?php
echo $this->Html->script('addFile');
```

And this **script** what Im using in View :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 3;
    var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap");
    var add_button      = $(".add_field_button");

    var x = 1;
    $(add_button).click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){
            x++;
            $(wrapper).append("<div><input type='file' name='data[files]' id='uploadFilefiles'/><a href='#' class='remove_field'>Kustuta</a></div>");
        }
     });

      $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
            e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
        })
});
```

I think that, the problem is in input names. If Im doing more inputs, then the inputs names are same, and thanks to this its uploading only one file in to webroot/files folder, but I want these all.

Can anybody help me or give me some tips.
Thanks !

Comment: name='data[files][]'

Comment: Yes I know that I need to do something like this, but if I just add [] in to view and script its doing the same thing, uploading only one file.

Comment: It creates an array, you should loop over the array and place the upload functionality inside of the loop. Check my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is someone with almost exactly the same issue as you have:
[Create multiple Upload File dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026284/create-multiple-upload-file-dynamically)

Try doing the same. I haven't programmed PHP for quite some time, but I guess you should replace `data[files]` to just `data[]`, so it creates a new array item for each field. Now you are giving each field the same name.

Then you can loop over them in your controller by using:

```
foreach($_FILES['data'] as $file){
  //do stuff with $file
}
```

EDIT 2:
As you are saying, you want to upload the files (not to a db). So I guess this should work:

```
public function uploadFile() {
        $filename = '';
            if ($this->request->is('post')) { // checks for the post values
                $uploadData = $this->data;
                foreach($uploadData as $file){

                if ( $file['size'] == 0 || $file['error'] !== 0) { // checks for the errors and size of the uploaded file
                    echo "Failide maht kokku ei tohi olla üle 5MB";
                    return false;
                }
                $filename = basename($file['name']); // gets the base name of the uploaded file
                $uploadFolder = WWW_ROOT. 'files';  // path where the uploaded file has to be saved
                $filename = $filename; // adding time stamp for the uploaded image for uniqueness
                $uploadPath =  $uploadFolder . DS . $filename;
                if( !file_exists($uploadFolder) ){
                    mkdir($uploadFolder); // creates folder if  not found
                }
                if (!move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $file)) {
                    return false;
                } 
                echo "Sa sisestasid faili(d): $filename";

            }       
         }    
    }
```

Comment: `Notice (8): Undefined index: tmp_name [APP\Controller\UploadFileController.php, line 22]`

Comment: still had uploadData defined on some rows, just changed it to file ;) try again haha

Comment: `Warning (2): move_uploaded_file() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given [APP\Controller\UploadFileController.php, line 22]`

Comment: Changed this second `$file` in this line to `$uploadPath`

Comment: fck , its not working correctly :S I can upload 2files, but If I upload 3files then only 2files going to folder.

Comment: change ```if(x < max_fields){``` in your javascript to ```if(x <= max_fields){```

Comment: its not helping , still uploading only 2 files in to folder

Comment: I think that now come these inputs with same name what Im doing with script.

Comment: Ye, I Inspected element , and saw .. One input name is data[] but these inputs what im making with script these names are data[files]. Why ?? This is this line in script what makes inputs : `$(wrapper).append("<div><input type='file' name='data[]' id='uploadFilefiles'/><a href='#' class='remove_field'>Kustuta</a></div>");`

Answer (score 0):

Try this function:

```
function multi_upload($file_id, $folder="", $types="") {
        $all_types = explode(",",strtolower($types));
        foreach($_FILES[$file_id]['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name ){
            if(!$_FILES[$file_id]['name'][$key]){
                $return[$key]= array('','No file specified');
                continue;
            }
            $file_title = $_FILES[$file_id]['name'][$key];
            $ext_arr = pathinfo($file_title, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            $ext = strtolower($ext_arr); //Get the last extension
            //Not really uniqe - but for all practical reasons, it is
            $uniqer = substr(md5(uniqid(rand(),1)),0,5);
            $file_name = $uniqer . '_' . $file_title;//Get Unique Name
            if($types!=''){
                if(in_array($ext,$all_types));
                else {
                    $result = "'".$_FILES[$file_id]['name'][$key]."' is not a valid file."; //Show error if any.
                    $return[$key]= array('',$result);
                    continue;
                }
            }
            //Where the file must be uploaded to
            if($folder) $folder .= '/';//Add a '/' at the end of the folder
            $uploadfile = $folder . $file_name;
            $result = '';
            //Move the file from the stored location to the new location
            if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$file_id]['tmp_name'][$key], $uploadfile)) {
                $result = "Cannot upload the file '".$_FILES[$file_id]['name'][$key]."'"; //Show error if any.
                if(!file_exists($folder)) {
                    $result .= " : Folder don't exist.";
                    } elseif(!is_writable($folder)) {
                    $result .= " : Folder not writable.";
                    } elseif(!is_writable($uploadfile)) {
                    $result .= " : File not writable.";
                }
                $file_name = '';
            } 
            else {
                if(!$_FILES[$file_id]['size']) { //Check if the file is made
                    @unlink($uploadfile);//Delete the Empty file
                    $file_name = '';
                    $result = "Empty file found - please use a valid file."; //Show the error message
                }
                else {
                    @chmod($uploadfile,0777);//Make it universally writable.
                }
            }
            $return[$key]=array($file_name,$result);
        }
        return $return;
    }
```

html: `<input type="file" name="data_file[]" id="uploadFilefiles">`

Call by `multi_upload("data_file","upload_to_folder","pdf,jpg,txt,bmp")`

Comment: `Warning (2): Missing argument 1 for UploadFileController::Uploadfile() [APP\Controller\UploadFileController.php, line 5]
Notice (8): Undefined variable: file_id [APP\Controller\UploadFileController.php, line 7]
Notice (8): Undefined index: [APP\Controller\UploadFileController.php, line 7]
Warning (2): Invalid argument supplied for foreach() [APP\Controller\UploadFileController.php, line 7]
Notice (8): Undefined variable: return [APP\Controller\UploadFileController.php, line 54]`

Comment: I dont have any file id , what I need to do with these lines ?

Comment: how do you call this function. first arg will be input file name. if file_name `upload_file[]` then `upload_file`

Comment: it is difficult to use the code that is completely revised. But thank you for trying to help.